# Change of original column leads to TEXT format in Excel sheet

Tags: oracle, excel, openquery, vba

This select in EXCEL VBA results to **numeric** format in Excel:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(dtb, 'SELECT col from table')"
```

But if I make some function on the column, it results as **text** format in Excel:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(dtb, 'SELECT sum(col) from table')"
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(dtb, 'SELECT col*1.0  from table')"
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(dtb, 'SELECT col-1    from table')"
```

I've tried `to_number(...)`, `to_number(to_char(...))` but it didn't helped.

Why? How can I resolve this situation?

**SOLUTION** (convert column to numeric using SQL server cast function)

```
strSQL = "SELECT cast(col# as numeric(10, 2)) col# " _
         "FROM OPENQUERY(dtb, 'SELECT sum(col) col# from table')"
```

Comment: try the to_number function around the expression : to_number(sum(col))

Comment: I've tried it, but it didn't helped.. still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION** (convert column to numeric using SQL server cast function)

```
strSQL = "SELECT cast(col# as numeric(10, 2)) col# " _
         "FROM OPENQUERY(dtb, 'SELECT sum(col) col# from table')"
```